# BCNF Decomposition and Keys

Tags: database, schema, normalization, 3nf, bcnf

I've been looking to decompose the following relation from its present state, into BCNF with three functional dependencies.

[image]

Taking the maxim

> *the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key*

I concluded that B-->C transitive functional dependency meant it was in 2NF, and should be decomposed to remove this into

[image]

This also, I think, should be in BCNF. However, my question is, does the A,B --> C FD break this - because it doesn't seem to match the **'nothing but the key'**, aspect of the maxim above? (And the 'B' part of the A,B --> FD is not a key attribute, rather 'B' is addition to the key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note that the three dependencies:

```
A → B
A B → D
B → C
```

are not a canonical cover (`A B → D` can be simplified to `A → D`, given `A → B`). So, the canonical cover is:

```
A → B
A → D
B → C
```

and since the key is `A`, you are correct in decomponing the relation in:

```
R1<(B, C), {B → C}>
R2<(A, B, D), {A → B, A → D}>
```

Note that all the dependencies satisfy the BCNF definition, since the key of `R1` is `B`, the key of `R2` is `A`, and each depedency has its LHS which is a key.